# Is 50 Images a minimum requirement to recognize a face of a person using Watson visual recognitionservice?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have question on Watson Visual recognition Service of bluemix?

Is 50 Images a minimum requirement to recognize a face of a person?

What would happen if we train with less than 50 images? What would be the consistency of the output in terms of facial recognition?

Requirement is, Retrieve the employee id of an employee by his facial(visual) recognition.

Is it achievable with Watson visual recognition Service?

In real time, it may be little hard to have 50 images of an employee or a person.
?

Thanks,

Priyanka

Comment: If i train with less images .The consistency of the output would be reduced .So I would like to know what would be the minimum images require to maintain the consistency of the output at least 80%?

Comment: You can follow my article, this article shows how to training one Good classifier on Visual Recognition

Answer (score 1):

When I use the Visual Recognition, I had the same doubt, after it, I search this [article](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/10/watson-visual-recognition-training-best-practices/) talking about good practices:

The accuracy you will see from your custom classifier depends directly on the quality of the training you perform.

On a basic level, images in training and testing sets should resemble each other. Significant visual differences between training and testing groups will result in poor performance results.

There are a number of additional factors that will impact the quality of your training beyond the resolution of your images. Lighting, angle, focus, color, shape, distance from subject, and presence of other objects in the image will all impact your training. Please note that Watson takes a holistic approach when being trained on each image. While it will evaluate all of the elements listed above, it cannot be tasked to exclusively consider a specific element.

So, the service works by using a *collection* of *classifiers*, each classifier is a single tag only and must be trained with it's own sets of `positive` and `negative` images. So, the professional recommend using a significantly greater amount of images to improve the performance and accuracy of your `classifier` such as 100s or 1000s of images.

- See one [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEs1imQmk-Y&feature=youtu.be) to verify how it works.
- Fork the [Example](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Visual-Recognition-Tile-Localization) in the video on Github.
- Official Documentation about [Guidelines](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/visual-recognition/customizing.html) for training classifiers.